# How do i subtract time from datetime in snowflake?

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

`pdt.startTime` is datetime

`s_first.FromTimeOfDay` is a time

I want to subtract the time drom the datetime. When i run the code below, Snowflake gives me this error `invalid type [CAST(S_FIRST.FROMTIMEOFDAY AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))] for parameter 'TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ'`

```
select (pdt.StartTime - (SELECT s_first.FromTimeOfDay::datetime FROM Shift s_first))
from RAW_CPMS_AAR.POWERBI_DowntimeTable AS PDT
```

When i try this:

```
select (pdt.StartTime::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) - (SELECT s_first.FromTimeOfDay::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) FROM Shift s_first))
from RAW_CPMS_AAR.POWERBI_DowntimeTable AS PDT
```

I get more or less the same error: `invalid type [CAST(S_FIRST.FROMTIMEOFDAY AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))] for parameter 'TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ'`

How do I convert the time into a datetime format so that I can subtract the two. It doesnt seem to me that there is a clear way to convert time into datetime in snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
select current_timestamp() as sample_timestamp
, time(sample_timestamp) as sample_time
, date(sample_timestamp) as sample_date;
```

Comment: not quite. i have a column that's timestamp that looks like this `2021-11-25 14:48:39.520` and another column that looks like this `06:00:00`. i want to subtract time from datetime so my result should look like `2021-11-25 8:48:39.520`. and if it's an earlier time in the day, it should go to the day prior.

Comment: ahh the dateadd function! https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html

Comment: this is it. i was thrown off by the name "dateadd" thank you

Answer (score 0):

A user pointed me in the right direction. i didnt realize i could use "dateadd" to also subtract time.

```
dateadd(HOUR, - (HOUR(current_timestamp())), temp.DateTime)
```